# Динамическое создание классов

Tags: javascript

Например, есть несколько классов `classA`, `classB` и мне необходимо создать класс динамически, как в `php`.

```
class classA {
  constructor(parametrs) {
    this.parametrs = JSON.parse(parametrs);
  }
};
class classB {
  constructor(parametrs) {
    this.parametrs = JSON.parse(parametrs);
  }
};
```

Как правильно создать класс по такому принципу:

```
let newClass = new 'classA' ('{"width":"0","height":"0"}');
```

Comment: всегда есть [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Но в данном случае даже он не нужен, достаточно просто сохранить классы в объект что-то вроде `var map = {classA, classB}`, и затем просто использовать `let newClass = new map['classA'] ('{"width":"0","height":"0"}');`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо) То что надо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае достаточно просто сохранить классы в объект что-то вроде

```
var map = {classA, classB}
```

и затем просто использовать

```
let newClass = new map['classA'] ('{"width":"0","height":"0"}');
```

```js
class classA {
  constructor(parametrs) {
    this.parametrs = JSON.parse(parametrs);
  }
};
class classB {
  constructor(parametrs) {
    this.parametrs = JSON.parse(parametrs);
  }
};

var map = {
  classA,
  classB
}

console.log(new map['classA']('{"width":"0","height":"0"}') instanceof classA);
console.log(new map['classB']('{"width":"0","height":"0"}') instanceof classB);
```

Comment: решили дать ответ, почему?

Comment: @doox911, прохожу по открытым вкладкам своим в браузере, сейчас время появилось :)